# Changing admin classes in runtime

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I want to change admin classes programmatically without restarting server. I want to for example change list displays of a model in runtime. Now it only changes when I restart the server... Example ([Versionadmin is an extention of modeladmin](https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion)):

```
admin.site.unregister(model)

class YourModelAdmin(VersionAdmin):
        list_display = new_list_display

admin.site.register(model, YourModelAdmin)
```

This works if I run it in admin.py, but if I run it when the admin site is already setup, nothing changes. Any idea how to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried reloading the module after you make changes?
Python 3+

```
import importlib.reload as reload
reload(admin)
```

Python 2.7+

```
reload(admin)
```